# django not serving static files. 404 error

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, static-files

I'm new to the django framework and I cannot get it to serve static files. I'm following a website tutorial [here](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/templates_static.html). The templates folder loads properly. I cannot access localhost:8000/static/

Here's the settings.py

```
    import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
    )

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '626+nh90b61sb)6@bp(v!o5g&&()s)g!@k*ay$tor!$nln88#*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tangoWithDjangoProject.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tangoWithDjangoProject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


STATICFILES_DIR = (
     STATIC_PATH,
    )
```

Here's index.html where I want to load the image

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rango Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Rango Index page</h1>
    <p><strong>{{boldmessage}}</strong></p>
    <p><a href="/rango/about/">About</a></p>
    <img src="{% static "images/steve.jpg" %}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be {% load staticfiles %} ??

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work

Comment: you also need `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` and point to your static folder. Template path is the path for your html templates. ... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR +  '/static/'
MEDIA_URL =  '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR + '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static('/templates/', document_root=settings.PROJECT_DIR + '/templates/')
```

Comment: but when i print BASE_DIR, its an empty string. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The original code I have works if i move my static folder inside the django-app folder. Can I share the code with you somewhere else? It's a lenghty piece of code.